# One word that can mean both teacher or student

Tags: single-word-requests

As part of educational systems there is often a division between two roles:

Teachers or educators give knowledge, while students or trainees receive knowledge.

Is there an abstraction over this distinction that describes simply a person being part of an educational system, regardless of whether it is a student or a teacher in particular?

Edit: In case there is no such general term, what about a word in the context of a single subject?

Comment: No. But you can find other categories they both fit into naturally: campus inhabitants, school attendees, etc.

Comment: mh. Any idea for something like that referring to students/teachers in the same subject?

Comment: As I said: no. But if you can find *something else* that ties them together, it’d be a useful lead. But there’s no hypernym for *student* and *teacher* that people use or would even recognize without an explanation.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be something when the subject ties them together... but I'll see what else I can find...

Comment: "Academic" (as a noun) is the term.  It just needs to be understood that it refers to someone who is reasonably devoted to learning, vs, say, a high school student who is more interested in playing sports and chasing girls.

Comment: What about scholar?

Comment: @MarcelKlehr One doesn't typically describe undergrads as scholars.  Usually used for professors, or preeminent researchers in the field. You certainly wouldn't call HS students or teachers scholars. I mean, when I was in a fancy-pants grammar school (age 5-10 or so), they called us "scholars", but it was, well, condescending is the wrong word ... maybe motivational? They didn't think of us as scholars, but they wanted us to think of ourselves as scholars.

Answer (score 3):

*Academic* might fit your needs:

> **Academic** *noun*
>
> a teacher or student at a college or university
>
> [Collins Dictionary - Academic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/academic)

* Bear in mind that this word within a college/university in certain places, might be understood to mean the faculty, not the student body.

Comment: Most people on hearing that word will assume it to be describing the faculty, not the students.

Comment: Dictionaries reflect the use of a word. Out of Meriam Webster, Collins, Dictionary.com, and Oxford, Meriam Webster is ambiguous while the rest give equivalent definitions.

Comment: I wasn’t asking a question, I was making a statement. If you use this word on campus, or about a campus, people will understand you to mean the faculty, not the student body. Maybe it would include grad students, but absolutely not undergrads.

Comment: OP hasn't given any context for the question. In such cases it is counterproductive to assume the worst case scenario for any answer, given that there will always be a context in which the word won't fit. However, I will clarify with an edit so that OP is not confused. Also, chill dude. If you don't like my answer downvote it and/or post your own.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But I wasn’t pointing out some obscure corner case. I am saying if you’re talking about schools at all, with anyone, anywhere, if you say “academics” they will not mentally include the students. Also, per your point about context: if you think the question is lacking sufficient context to be unambiguous, you shouldn’t answer. For example here, your edit includes *college/university*, but that raises the question of, say, high school. If OP’s context is HS, then *academics* is inapplicable to both students *and* teachers.

Comment: +1 @DanBron As a student (and even after having graduating), I always considered myself an academic. (As did any classmates and teachers I spoke to.). The word has a broader meaning than either *student* or *teacher*. I've always thought of *anybody* attending university, in any capacity, as being an academic. Your interpretation of it applying solely to teachers is contrary to dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to both the teachers *and* students of a college one might just call them "the college community".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please consider including some usage in your answer. See [*How to reference material written by others*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).